# TouchableXXX will auto triggered when app start in reactnative

Tags: react-native, touchablehighlight, onpress

I am trying to wrap touchable items following [this tortial](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/handling-touches.html)

And the problem I found is that the navigation will be auto trigger by the launch of the app, it will navigate to the detail page without press on it.
And when navigate back, the touchable items can't be pressed anymore, when pressed, an error will be thrown out.

I made a minimum app to indict that out:

```
import React , { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet,FlatList, Text, View,TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import {
  StackNavigator,
} from 'react-navigation';


class Detail extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: "Detail",
  };

  render(){
    return(
      <View>
          <Text>{this.props.value}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class MyItem extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.props.nav("Detail", {value: this.props.value})}>
        <Text> {this.props.value}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class Home extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: "Home",
  };
  render() {
    const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          data = {[
            {key: "1"},
            {key: "2"},
            {key: "3"}
          ]
          }
          renderItem = {({item}) => <MyItem nav={navigate} value={item.key} />}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});

const App = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: Home },
  Detail: { screen: Detail },
})

export default App
```

Since it's very hard to describe this issue with my bad English, I also made a [youtube video (about 20M)](https://youtu.be/ybsQn8DJ3qo) to indict this problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class MyItem extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { this.props.nav("Detail", {value: this.props.value})} }>
        <Text> {this.props.value}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

As per request

```
class MyItem extends Component{
  handleClick = () => {
    const { nav, value } = this.props;
    nav("Detail", {value});
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.handleClick}>
        <Text> {this.props.value}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: And could you give an example if I want to make a `_onPressButton(value)` function as the tutorial does with this situation? Thanks.  Don't know how to pass all these parameters to the function.

Comment: I've updated my answer, let me know if any problems arise.